# Error al compilar una clase en C++

Tags: c++, clase

Me salen dos errores y no sé el motivo.

Enunciado del ejercicio:

> Implementar el *TAD* (tipo abstracto de datos) `ConjuntoCadenas`.
>
> Este *TAD* consistirá en una estructura capaz de almacenar un conjunto de como máximo 100 cadenas diferentes.
>
> El *TAD* se implementará mediante una clase llamada `ConjuntoCadenas` en un módulo llamado `ccadenas` (`ccadenas.h` y `ccadenas.cpp`).
>
> El espacio de nombres utilizado en este módulo debe ser `modulosp2`.
>
> Las operaciones que tendrá definidas este *TAD* son:
>
> - `leerDeFichero`: Recibirá como parámetro el nombre de un fichero con una cadena por línea. El método añadirá las cadenas que aparecen en el fichero al conjunto.
> - `escribirAFichero`: Recibirá como parámetro el nombre de un fichero y lo
>     sobreescribirá con las cadenas que contiene el conjunto.
> - `incluir`: Recibe como parámetro una cadena y la añade al conjunto. Si la cadena ya existe en el conjunto no hará nada.
> - `pertenece`: Recibe como parámetro una cadena y devuelve si pertenece o no al conjunto.
> - `eliminar`: Recibe como parámetro una cadena y si pertenece al conjunto la elimina.
> - `listar`: Muestra todas las cadenas del conjunto por pantalla.
> - `vaciar`: Elimina todos los elementos del conjunto.

Solo hice el primer punto para ver qué tal arrancaba.

Este es el código **ccadenas.h**:

```
#ifndef CCADENAS_H
#define CCADENAS_H

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

namespace modulosp2 {
    class ConjuntoCadenas {
        public:
        void leerDeFichero(std::string fichero);

        private:
        static const int MAX=100;
        typedef std::string TDatos[MAX];
        struct conjunto {
            int tamanyo=0;
            TDatos cadena;
        };
        conjunto datos;
        std::string linea;  
    };
}
#endif // CCADENAS_H
```

El código **ccadenas.cpp**:

```
#include "ccadenas.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

namespace modulosp2 {
    void ConjuntoCadenas::leerDeFichero(string fichero) {
        ifstream fin;

        fin.open(fichero.c_str());

        while (!fin.eof()) {
            if(datos.tamanyo<MAX) {
                lleno=false;
                getline(fin, linea);
                datos.cadena[datos.tamanyo]=linea;
                datos.tamanyo++;
            } else {
                lleno=true;
            }
        }
        fin.close();
    }
}
```

Del cual me salen los siguientes errores:

> undefined reference to WinMain@16
>
> error: ld returned 1 exit status

Por último el código principal `conjuntos.cpp`:

```
#include "ccadenas.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace modulosp2;
using namespace std;

int menu() {
    int op;
    cout<<"\t0. Fin"<<endl;
    cout<<"\t1. Leer de fichero"<<endl;
    while(op<0||op>1) {
        cout<<"\tOpcion?: "<<endl;
        cin>>op;
    }
    return op;
}

int main() {
    int op;
    string fichero;
    ConjuntoCadenas concad;
    do {
        op=menu();
        switch(op) {
            case 1:
                cout<<"\tIntroduzca el nombre del fichero"<<endl;
                getline(cin, fichero);
                concad.leerDeFichero(fichero);
            break;
        }
    }while(op!=0);
    return 0;
}
```

Del cual me salen los siguientes errores:

> modulosp2::ConjuntoCadenas::leerDeFichero(std::string)
>
> error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: ¿Te has asegurado de que el nombre del fichero que escribe el usuario se corresponda con un fichero existente y que se encuentre en la misma ruta que el programa?

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow en Español. Por favor, [edita](http://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/56286/edit) la pregunta y añade algunos datos mas: orden exacta al compilar (compilador y argumentos pasados), texto exacto del error que obtienes, ... en fín, todo lo que pueda aportar información a tu problema. Los asuntos de programación requieren datos **exactos** ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parece que tienes que crear un proyecto e incluir todos los archivos para construir la aplicación.
En el primer caso, al compilar cadenas.cpp, lo que te esta diciendo es que no encuentra la función main() del proyecto.
En el segundo, al compilar conjuntos.cpp, te esta diciendo que no sabe nada de la clase ConjuntoCadenas.

Comment: Tengo todos los archivos en un solo proyecto, todos en la misma carpeta

Comment: Como te dice @Trauma, deberías indicar las opciones de compilación que utilizas ya que pudiera ser que estés intentando compilar una aplicación windows cuando lo tuyo es una aplicación de consola.

Comment: Lo siento pero soy nuevo en esto, ¿como puedo mostrar las opciones de compilacion?. Utilizo CodeBlocks

Comment: Si yo estuviera en tu situación para asegurarme y _descartar_ ese error, trataría de poner todo el código en un solo archivo y compilarlo.